# Need to display "click" event to act like EditNode Popup without save and cancel button. Only to show the Nodepopup/edgepopup

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I have a working code from below example.

http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/manipulationEditEdgeNoDrag.html

But I would like to add a "click" event to display a node properties(NodePopUp) and edge properties.

So when I click a node, a NodePopUp should show up without having save and cancel button. Same for EdgePopup too.

The left image - Clicked the Node 0. But I should click edit -> edit node -> then displays the popup of node properties.

I would like to skip these steps and when I click a node/edge corresponding node/edge popup needs to be displayed without save and cancel button.

[image]
Could anyone give me a suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: please show us what you have tried and where you are stuck and ask a specific question. "Could anyone give me a suggestion to achive this." is not an on-topic question for SO

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have edited my question. In my project I have lots of nodes and each node is having 20 fields in a popup window. That's the reason we want to select a node and only display the fields(no editing). so that we could edit the node if the node values to be changed.

Comment: Still, your question is very broad. I've added an outline answer, but there's lots of details which you have to deal with. If you get problems with those, please ask one question at a time (in separate threads) to stay on-topic in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is to handle `click` [event](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#Events) (`network.on("click", ...)`) and open the popup (if you opt the code of the cited example, you can see that it is done via the `editNode` helper and also by assigning `document.getElementById('node-operation').innerHTML = "Add Node";`; I have to admit, the code there is not very reusable, you may want to take a look at [my implementation](http://yakovl.bplaced.net/TW/GraphTools/GraphEditor.html) of graph editor, see the `config.macros.graph.createEditPopup` helper, it's more reusable for such things). So will have something like

```
network.on("click", function(clickProperties)
{
    var popup = document.querySelector('.my_popup'); // adjust selector to the class/id you use

    if(clickProperties.nodes.length == 1) // you want this for just one node clicked, right?
    {
        var id = clickProperties.nodes[0];

        popup.style.display = 'block';
        popup.textContent = 'one node selected: '+id; // fill popup input fields etc
    }
    else if(clickProperties.nodes.length == 0)
    {
        popup.style.display = 'none';
    }
})
```

(see how this works [with just div instead of popup](http://jsfiddle.net/b5zash0r/4/)) You also will need to handle hiding and showing the save/cancel buttons by adding/removing `display: none;` css to elements; or, better, you can recreate the popup each time to avoid messing with those. You also have to decide how are you going to close the popup (you can skip hiding "cancel" or substitute it with a cross button or close on pressing esc or on click elsewhere...)

Comment: I do have editNode and that popsup good. My question is - instead of clicking the Edit->EditNode -> NodePopUp, I need to display the NodePopUp immediately. When I just click or hover over the Node the NodePopUp should be displayed. Hope you could understand now my point!

Comment: @user3280899 yes, I totally understand, and the answer describes how to do that. Is there anything unclear about it?

Comment: @user3280899 I've tested and fixed a couple of bugs, though; and added the fiddle that demonstrates how click handling works, you just have to adapt it to popup opening

Comment: Okay. But your "my implementation" does not help me. But the other example provides just alert message. I will try to use the click function as you suggested in your reply. Will work on it in the weekend. Thank you.

Comment: hi @user3280899, how's your progress? I've made a small update so that if you haven't implemented the popup, it will help you a bit more: http://jsfiddle.net/b5zash0r/4/ Note that I haven't implemented popup hiding on click outside the canvas; I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: (and only implemented hide/show thing, not filling all the fields etc)

Comment: Hi @YakovL , I have not worked on it yet. Your hide/show would help me for sure. My popup should be used as like #NodePopUp #EdgePopUp, same like node and edge edit. I think I could achieve it. Thanks for your help. Will update once I finish this task.